# Are there custom graphics sets for Goblin Camp?

Tags: goblin-camp

I love Dwarf Fortress, but part of what makes it playable for me is the customization of graphics sets.  I use the [Mike Mayday](http://mayday.w.staszic.waw.pl/df.php) custom package.

I'm interested in Goblin Camp, but again I don't want to deal with the hardcore ascii. Are there custom graphics for Goblin Camp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [version 0.14](http://www.goblincamp.com/2011/02/version-v0-14-release/), tilesets have been implemented. A graphical tileset now comes alongside the classic ASCII in v0.14, but anybody can make their own with a little help on [Tileset Modding from the wiki](http://goblincampwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=TilesetModding). A [Tileset Repository](http://goblincampwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tileset_Repository) is available on the wiki too if you don't like the one that comes with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, but there is a team hard at work, view their progress [here](http://www.goblincamp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=44).

Also originally I felt the same way, but learning the ASCII for gobliln camp is no way comparable to learning it for DF, because mostly you don't have to know what everything is.  There's tool tips for the map, so you don't have to memorize workshops, and if you need to find something, you can look it up in the stock manager (Next to the resource name is the ASCII symbol that represents it).